# Using JNI to call a Java method from C++ that has non-primitive output

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to call the following Java method (from an external jar file) from C++

```
Game game = GameLoader.loadGameFromName("My game name");
```

Where the function signature for `loadGameFromName` is

`public static Game loadGameFromName(String name)`

and `GameLoader` is a Java public final class.  Also `Game` is a public final class.

The code I have used to attempt to call this method is

```
jclass gameLoader = env->FindClass("player/GameLoader");
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(gameLoader,"loadGameFromName","(Ljava/lang/String;)Lgame/Game");
```

Here the `gameLoader` class was successfully found in the first line however the `loadGameFromName` method was not found in the second line.

Also, it might be relevant that I was able to successfully call a different method from `GameLoader` which was

`String[] games = GameLoader.listGames()`

with the following code

```
jclass gameLoader = env->FindClass("player/GameLoader");
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(gameLoader,"listGames","()[Ljava/lang/String;");
jobjectArray stringArray = (jobjectArray) env->CallStaticObjectMethod(gameLoader,mid);
```

So that code works fine.  So it looks like the main difference here is that `loadGameFromName` returns a `Game` object rather than a Java string object.  Also, it might be relevant to note that I am able to successfully find the `Game` class with  `jclass game = env->FindClass("game/Game");`.

Is there something wrong with the way I am calling `GetStaticMethodID` for the `loadGameFromName` method? I have tried to search for examples of calling Java methods with JNI that return arbitrary Java objects like `Game` but I couldn't find any.

Comment: You are missing a closing `;` in the type descriptor for the Game class -> `"(Ljava/lang/String;)Lgame/Game;"`.

Comment: @JornVernee haha yep it looks like that was the problem.  Thank you